# Rspec 'Cannot Load Such File -- Date (Load Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

first SO question here so feel free to correct any faux pas on my part.

I'm running `rspec spec/models` from the app directory of a Rails 4.1.0 app and I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- Date (LoadError)
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /home/david/Projectsam/spec/models/batch_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I checked a few other similar questions, but they all seemed to be related to Gems or making sure to run the rspec command from your project directory. I'm a bit lost seeing as I thought 'Date' is a core module, not a gem.  I get a similar error when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/models`

There's a good chance I'm missing something stupid, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.  Thanks in advance!

**Update:** So in an attempt to clarify this problem bit more, I'm getting this more general error when I run `rspec spec`:

```
~/myapp/spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant DashboardController (NameError)
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

**Update 2:**

So there's a `require Date` in one of the spec files that seems to be causing this - commenting this out lets rspec run without any problems. The weird thing is that rspec works fine on a MacOS without commenting out the `require` statement.

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code posted to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure, I took out the gemfile and spec_helper info since I guess those might not be necessary. Thanks for taking the time to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out using the rails generate command created some cruft that required 'spec helper' instead of 'rspec,' causing a dependency issue. Dumb mistake, I'll close this.